# How to decode json for the json data getting in my url?

Tags: json, getjson

http://example.com/api/orderDetails.php?{"user_id":1,"itemList":[{"max_price":120,"min_price":100,"trend":"high","c_price":110,"status":"1","type":"veg","item_id":19},{"max_price":200,"min_price":100,"trend":"low","c_price":100,"status":"1","type":"veg","item_id":224}],"table_no":"1"}

Comment: Where are you receiving the URL ? What is the type of your application ?

Comment: I am getting this url from android.I have to insert each item in my db .Problem is how do i decode this json so that i can get array data

Comment: Just added the answer, but you need your URL is a valid json format and to be sure you do this you have to make a response header forced with json content.

Comment: $_REQUEST is a post or get (variable send by form submit or ajax) here is an URL i think you really don't known what you are going to do :(, cannot send via GET with a string with speccial characters as json are you need to send via ajax javascript or via post serialize and unserialized from PHP and json_decode.

Answer (score 0):

how to decode from php?

```
 $object_from_json = json_decode('{"user_id":1,"itemList":[{"max_price":120,"min_price":100,"trend":"high","c_price":110,"status":"1","type":"veg","item_id":19},{"max_price":200,"min_price":100,"trend":"low","c_price":100,"status":"1","type":"veg","item_id":224}],"table_no":"1"}');

//or

$array_from_json = json_decode('{"user_id":1,"itemList":[{"max_price":120,"min_price":100,"trend":"high","c_price":110,"status":"1","type":"veg","item_id":19},{"max_price":200,"min_price":100,"trend":"low","c_price":100,"status":"1","type":"veg","item_id":224}],"table_no":"1"}', true);
//then you got a Array in PHP
//var_dump($array_from_json);

//with an URL 
$array_from_json_url = json_decode(file_get_contents($json_url), true);
//var_dump($array_from_json_url);
```

You need on your page PHP orderDetails.php to add the response header need to be a json format before the echo

```
header("Content-type:application/json");
//$output is array or object PHP
echo json_encode($oupout);
```

Comment: How do I get it through my url by $_REQUEST method.I tried by $array_from_json = json_decode($_REQUEST, true); but getting null in my response